# Why NuGet is it getting MVVMLight for all frameworks and all platforms?

Tags: mvvm-light, nuget, nuget-package

NuGet is getting MVVMLight binaries for WPF, SL3, SL4, SL5, WP7 
I don't really like that. 
Is there a way to make it get just for the framework which the project is using?

How is generally NuGet working for other packages, it maybe something which the MVVMLight author should do when creating the NuGet package?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a nuget convention to include libraries of different framework versions inside a unique package. This makes it easier for the package consumer, there's only one version of a package to install.

When installing a package through NuGet Package Manager (UI or console), NuGet will only add  references to libraries that targets your project's framework. Note: all the package content is unpacked to "\packages\", including libraries that aren't used.

Example:
I created a SL4 application and installed MVVMLightLibs. Only GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4 and GalaSoft.MvvmLight.SL4 are added as a reference.

[see nuget documentation : Supporting_Multiple_.NET_Framework_Versions_and_Profiles](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Supporting_Multiple_.NET_Framework_Versions_and_Profiles)

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. But it doesn't sound to me like a good idea. Imagine you are using a framework which has its own dependencies. Some of these dependencies might have their own dependencies in turn, and so on. I don't think it's wise that it downloads ALL the libraries of ALL the frameworks it supports. I can end up having on my disk 80MB when actually the size of library I am using is 10MB. I haven't yet tried NuGet for big frameworks, like Telerik for example.

Comment: Why isn't NuGet offering a feature for the user which adds a package to his project to allow selecting a specific platform\framework?  This  instead of detecting the platform and framework, which might be difficult to do for NuGet.

Comment: Obviously NuGet is actually able to detect the framework used by the project, that's how it selects the references from the package. Then why doesn't it do that when creating the package folder? It can only put there the references for the framework version used by the project. I know projects can target different frameworks. You maybe should have more control of this somehow.

Comment: Size hasn't been a common problem, most packages are under a few MB and only a few are this size due to multiple target frameworks. If this is a concern should be addressed I suggest you start this discussion in [NuGet Forums](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions) or file a [NuGet Issue](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem).